# Running multiple bash scripts with different names in parallel

Tags: bash, scripting, gnu-parallel

I need to run a command for each individual instance of a given variable name in parallel. Sometimes, there might be 4 variables, other times there might be 100. For example, say I have this particular dataset as:

```
datanames='KQPW KMMX KMKO KZAO'
```

I need to run a process for each which is to be run in parallel with one-another. In other words, I need to run process1 for KQPW while running process1 for KMMX while ... etc. Process1 requires input based on the variablename.

From the tutorials I have read, and some initial digging, I have installed the GNU 'parallel' command. I have put all of the datanames into a textfile called "run.txt":

```
KQPW.csh
KMMX.csh
KMKO.csh
KZAO.csh
```

wherein each of the `.csh` files contains the command for calling process1 with the unique variable name as the necessary input to process1. The question is, how do I run all four of these commands at once? I tried:

```
cat run.txt | parallel
```

but nothing happened. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick demonstration of executing scripts based as described in parallel, without using any external tools:

```
#!/bin/bash
datanames='KQPW KMMX KMKO KZAO'
datanamesarray=($datanames)
for item in ${datanamesarray[@]}; do
  ( ./${item}.csh; sleep 10 ) &
done
echo waiting..
wait
echo done
```

Executing this will display `waiting..` followed by a ten second delay as all of the subshells are executed in parallel.  `wait` will pause the parent script until all subshells have terminated before proceeding.  The `echo`, `sleep`, and `wait` statements are here for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: How is that better than `for item in $datanames;`?

Comment: That will also work in this case, but I happen to prefer to iterate over an array, so I reflexively converted your space-delimeted string.

Comment: So the issue is that it is running everything still at once..

Comment: I don't understand.  I thought you _wanted_ everything to run in parallel?

Comment: i think this method only runs a single job each time, so this is not really running parallel

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Clearly you can only _start_ one at a time, but the `&` token backgrounds each started process, so they continue to run as each new one is started.  It will only _start_ one job at a time but starting a job is nearly instantaneous, and they will all run _concurrently_, and the script as demonstrated here will then wait until all jobs are finished.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work. If you can do:

```
$ KMMX.csh
```

then GNU Parallel should also be able to run the script. The first debugging step is to run `parallel` with `--dry-run`, which will tell you what is being run:

```
cat run.txt | parallel --dry-run
```

There are, however, several things in your question that puzzles me:

- The title of the question mentions `bash` but you call your scripts `*.csh` Is your interactive shell `bash` but the scripts `csh`-files?
- You do not mention that you have put the files in a dir in your `$PATH`, yet you do not refer to the scripts with path (e.g. `./KMMX.csh`). That could explain why it does not work. Though you ought to get an error message.
- You do not mention that you have `chmod +x` the files. That could explain why it does not work. Though you ought to get an error message.

But most of all I worry that you are doing this harder on yourself than it needs to be. GNU Parallel is designed to build commands from a template, and it sounds as if your `*.csh`-files are also built from a template with the only change being the dataname.

My guess is that you can change your setup to:

```
$ parallel doit {} ::: KQPW KMMX KMKO KZAO
```

where `doit` is a script/function that takes the dataname as an argument.

I will highly encourage you to watch the intro videos for a quick introduction: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 Then look at the EXAMPLEs after the list of OPTIONS (Use LESS=+/EXAMPLE:      man parallel). That will give you an idea of what GNU parallel is capable of.  Then spend a couple of hours walking through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial).

Your command line will love you for it.